# Is there a reason as to why my program is not outputting anything?

Tags: python

This post is about a problem that I have encountered on a challenge that was assigned to me. The challenge is: you are in a pizza shop, and you are making software to calculate the price of orders. There are 4 customer inputs: pizza, drinks, wings, and coupons. the customer can order any arbitrary number of pizzas - including zero - and this goes for all of the other inputs. the wings, drinks, and coupons are all keyworded inputs, whereas the pizzas are not. All inputs are in lists, except the coupon is stored in a list. Pizzas can have any number of toppings, and people are charged extra for each topping. Here is a sample input:

```
cost_calculator([], ['pepperoni', 'mushroom'], drinks = ['tub', 'small'], wings = [10, 20], coupon = 0.1)
```

In the above example, the "[], [pepperoni, mushroom]" details two pizzas, the "drinks = ['tub', 'small']" details  two drinks, the "wings = [10,20]" details two orders of wings (10-piece, 20-piece), and the coupon takes 10% off the order.

Additionally, there is a tax of 6.25% which is added at the end of the program.

The problem is that the code that I have written does not output anything. I have looked it over countless times and I am not sure why it doesn't work. If one is interested in the challenge I am attempting - here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZZ0lK6ws_jcScWbbJawfAly8E4SJ1du7-azEBi9mWtI/edit?usp=sharing). Before anyone tells me that there is no print function - I know, there is a grader that I input this into, but for testing, I have been using print functions, and they still are not outputting anything. Forward apology for my terrible variables/

```
def cost_calculator(*pizza, **others):
    # write your code here
    call =  ((toppers(pizza) + drinkers(others) + wingers(others))) 
    interest = (call * coupons(others)) + (call * 0.0625)
    return round(interest, 2)

def toppers(toppers):
    if (len(toppers) == 0): 
        return 0
    topCost = 13.00
    j = 0
    toppings = {"pepperoni" : 1.00, "mushroom": 0.5, "olive": 0.5, "anchovy": 2.00, "ham" : 1.5}
    while (j < len(toppers)):
        for i in toppers:
            b = 0
            for thing in i:
                gg = thing[b]
                if gg in toppings:
                    topCost += toppings[gg]
                    j+=1
            
    return topCost
    

def drinkers (drinkers):
    drinks = {"small" : 2.00, "medium" : 3.00, "large":3.5, "tub":3.75}
    pricers  = 0.00
    r = 0
    while (r < len(drinkers)):
        for key, i in wingers:
            b = 0
            if key == "drinks":
                for thing in i:
                    gg = thing[b]
                    if gg in drinks:
                        pricers += drinks[gg]
                        r+=1
    return pricers
    
def wingers (wingers):
    if (len(wingers) == 0):
          return 0
    wings = {10:5.00 , 20:9.00 , 40:17.50, 100:48.00}
    wingices = 0.00
    kk = 0
    while (kk < len(wingers)):
        for key, i in wingers:
            b = 0
            if key == "wings":
                for thing in i:
                    gg = thing[b]
                    if gg in wings:
                        wingices += wings[gg]
                        kk+=1
    return wingices

def coupons(cups):
    cupz = 1.00
    for key,i in cups.items():
        if key == "coupon":
            cupz = 0.00
            cupz += i
            return 1 - cupz
    
    return cupz
```

Comment: I suspect you have an infinite loop in `toppers()`. You only increment `j` in the last `if`. If that condition doesn't succeed, you'll be stuck at `j = 0`.

Comment: `but for testing, I have been using print functions` Really?  I don't see any `print()` calls in this code anywhere.

Comment: "except the coupon is stored in a list" -- no, not coupon is a single number.

Comment: Did you try to run this code? Right off the bat, I get `NameError: 'function' object is not iterable` because you name your functions the same as their input argument, for example `wingers(wingers)`

Comment: And I would add: I suggest that you start with a solution that works when you use the fact that the assignment allows you to assume that you know the input. So instead of "finding" e.g. the input list `drink` in `others`, just assume that you have an input that is `drinks`. Your code is unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does run into an endless loop here:

```
def toppers(toppers):
    if (len(toppers) == 0):
        return 0
    topCost = 13.00
    j = 0
    toppings = {"pepperoni": 1.00, "mushroom": 0.5, "olive": 0.5, "anchovy": 2.00, "ham": 1.5}
    while (j < len(toppers)):
        for i in toppers:
            b = 0
            for thing in i:
                gg = thing[b]
                if gg in toppings:
                    topCost += toppings[gg]
                    j += 1
    return topCost
```

You call this with a list of two strings (`toppers`). You start with index `j` = 0.

Then you iterate over the two items in `toppers`. Then within each item you iterate over the characters in that item. Then you check if the item string has the `b`th character (always the `0`th character since you don't change `b`) as key of toppings. Which it never does. So you endlessly check if `p` (first letter of `pepperoni`) is a key in `toppings` and since it never is you never increase `j` and get stuck endlessly.

You probably want to do something else, probably it would be helpful to break it down into smaller steps and e.g. `print()` to see if it does the right thing up until that point.

Also I think you use way too many and complicated loop structures. Here is how you could write the method in a simpler way:

```
def get_cost_for_toppers(toppers):
        if len(toppers) == 0:
            return 0
        # dictionary of costs
        available_toppings = {"pepperoni": 1.00, "mushroom": 0.5, "olive": 0.5, "anchovy": 2.00, "ham": 1.5}
        # base cost
        topCost = 13.00
        # iterate over the strings in toppers
        for t in toppers:
            # add the price found in dictionary for this topper
            if t in available_toppings:
                topCost += available_toppings[t]
        return topCost
```